# Делаю приложение todo на kivy. Но TextInput не работает.

Tags: python, kivy

[image: Вот TextInput но он не реагирует. Disabled отключен]

```
#:import C kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#:import main main
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import TextInput kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput


<UI>:
<BaseScreen>:
    td_list_view: list_view
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: C('#ff777b')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            pos: 0, 450
            Label:
                text: "Tasks"
                font_size: 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            pos: 0, 130
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 310
            ListView:
                id: list_view
                adapter:
                    ListAdapter(data = [""], cls=main.ToDoListButton)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
            pos: 86, 15
            spacing: 15

            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 50, 50
                background_normal: "plus.png"
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                    root.manager.current = 'task'

            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 50, 50
                background_normal: "done.png"
                on_press: root.update()


<AddTaskScreen>:
    text_input: text_input
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: C('#ff777b')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            pos: 0, 450
            Label:
                text: "Tasks"
                font_size: 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            pos: 0, 350
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            CTextInput:
                id: text_input
                focus: True
                text: "Add your Task"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 15
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 100
            pos: 69, 15

            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 50, 50
                background_color: C("#f06d73")
                background_normal: "go-back.png"
                color: C("#ffffff")
                font_size: 15
                bold: True
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                    root.manager.current = 'base'

            Button:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 75, 75
                background_color: C("#f06d73")
                background_normal: ""
                text: "Add Task"
                color: C("#ffffff")
                font_size: 15
                bold: True
                on_press: root.add_task()

<CTextInput@TextInput>:
    focus: True
    readonly: False


import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex as C
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, FadeTransition, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import sqlite3
kivy.require('1.10.0')
__version__ = '0.1'
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Window.size = (288, 512)
file = 'tasks.json'
class UI(FloatLayout):
    pass
class BaseScreen(Screen):

    td_list_view = ObjectProperty()
    def update(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Tasks.sqlite')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT do FROM tasks')
        while True:
            row = []
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if row == None:
                break
            for task in row:
                task = str(task)
                self.td_list_view.adapter.data.extend([task])
                self.td_list_view._trigger_reset_populate()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    def task_done(self):
        if self.td_list_view.adapter.selection:
            selection = self.td_list_view.adapter.selection[0].text
            conn = sqlite3.connect('Tasks.sqlite')
            print(selection)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute('DELETE FROM tasks WHERE do == ("%s")'%selection)
            conn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            self.td_list_view.adapter.data.remove(selection)
            self.td_list_view._trigger_reset_populate()



class AddTaskScreen(Screen):
    text_input = ObjectProperty()
    bs = BaseScreen
    def add_task(self):
       # with open(file, 'w') as fileObject:
        #    fileObject.write(self.text_input.text+"\n")
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Tasks.sqlite')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tasks (do) VALUES ("%s")'%(self.text_input.text))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

class ToDoListButton(ListItemButton):
    pass

Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class TodoApp(App):
    title = "To do"

    def on_start(self):
        pass

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(BaseScreen(name="base"))
        sm.add_widget(AddTaskScreen(name="task"))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TodoApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


Builder.load_string('''
<Test>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    padding:15
    spacing:25
    CTextInput:
        id:pole
        focus:True
        text:'Add your task'
    Button:
        text:'Add task'
        on_press:root.press(pole.text)
    Label:
        id:msg
        text:""

<CTextInput@TextInput>:
    focus:True
    readonly:False
''')


class Test(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def press(self,temp):

        self.ids.msg.text=temp

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Нет оно вообще не работает. То что написано в TextInput он добавляет. Но сам TextInput не работает точнее Невозможно ничего написать. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Можете объяснить что вы хотели этим кодом написать а то непонятно Вроде написал.

Comment: Работает. Даже на телефоне проверял. То, что я ввожу в textinput печатает в терминале, правда на телефоне я добавил ещё label, и текст этого лейбла меняется в соответствии с текстом в инпуте. Когда вызывается функция root.add_task()  в неё передайте параметры взятые из id инпута. В моем случае это root.press(pole.text). Разве не так?

Comment: Создал такой же виджет как и у вас - CTextInput. Все равно работает - редактирует и выводит.

Comment: Сделал так же Но оно все так же не работает. То что написано в TextInput работает но Сам TextINput не печатается, точнее нельзя ничего написать. Можете посмотреть вот ссылка https://github.com/webdos24/Test_Todo. Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: Да. На компе так и есть - не хочет редактировать, почему-то теряет фокус. Но если держать зажатой кнопку мыши в поле ввода, то фокус не теряется. На телефоне таких проблем нет. Так что... Мой ответ не есть ответ)

Comment: А проверили тот код, что я скинул.

Comment: Да спасибо все работает. Как вы и сказали на windows не работал. Перешел на linux заработало. Спасибо

Comment: А может вы отредактируете свой вопрос, а то решение, все же не найдено.