# Создаю приложение todo на kivy. Хочу сделать так чтобы при запуске приложение записи из БД загрузились

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Хочу сделать так чтобы при запуске приложение записи из БД загрузились. Но метод из другого класса не работает можете объяснить почему?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex as C
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, FadeTransition, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import sqlite3
kivy.require('1.10.0')
__version__ = '0.1'
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Window.size = (288, 512)
file = 'tasks.json'
class UI(FloatLayout):
    pass
class BaseScreen(Screen):

    td_list_view = ObjectProperty()
    def update(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Tasks.sqlite')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT do FROM tasks')
        while True:
            row = []
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if row == None:
                break
            for task in row:
                task = str(task)
                self.td_list_view.adapter.data.extend([task])
                self.td_list_view._trigger_reset_populate()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    def task_done(self):
        if self.td_list_view.adapter.selection:
            selection = self.td_list_view.adapter.selection[0].text
            conn = sqlite3.connect('Tasks.sqlite')
            print(selection)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute('DELETE FROM tasks WHERE do == ("%s")'%selection)
            conn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            self.td_list_view.adapter.data.remove(selection)
            self.td_list_view._trigger_reset_populate()



class AddTaskScreen(Screen):
    text_input = ObjectProperty()
    bs = BaseScreen
    def add_task(self):
       # with open(file, 'w') as fileObject:
        #    fileObject.write(self.text_input.text+"\n")
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Tasks.sqlite')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tasks (do) VALUES ("%s")'%(self.text_input.text))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

class ToDoListButton(ListItemButton):
    pass

Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class TodoApp(App):
    title = "To do"

    def on_start(self):
        BaseScreen.update

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(BaseScreen(name="base"))
        sm.add_widget(AddTaskScreen(name="task"))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TodoApp().run()
```

Comment: `BaseScreen.update` -> `BaseScreen.update()`? Хотя не, фигня какая-то... `sm.add_widget(BaseScreen(name="base"))` тут вы добавляете этот виджет. А тут у класса `BaseScreen.update` обращаетесь к ссылке на метод объекта класса. Хотя, наверное, вы хотели тот виджет в `BaseScreen(name="base")` вызывать

Comment: Извините Я не понял можете помочь https://github.com/webdos24/tododo Это ссылка на проект. Пожалуйста.

Comment: Вообще приложение при запуске должно возвращать Записи из БД как в других приложениях ToDo List. Но не могу понять как это можно реализовать. Метод из класса BaseScreen не вызывается. Если знаете или же догадываетесь можете помочь ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте:

```
...

class TodoApp(App):
    title = "To do"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.base_screen = BaseScreen(name="base")

    def on_start(self):
        self.base_screen.update()

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(self.base_screen)
        sm.add_widget(AddTaskScreen(name="task"))
        return sm

...
```

---

Если вне конструктора, то в методе `build`, т.к. он по описанию похож на "конструктор" тем что вызывается при инициализации (приложения) и один раз:

> Initializes the application; it will be called only once.

```
class TodoApp(App):
    title = "To do"

    def on_start(self):
        self.base_screen.update()

    def build(self):
        self.base_screen = BaseScreen(name="base")

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(self.base_screen)
        sm.add_widget(AddTaskScreen(name="task"))
        return sm
```

Comment: WoW работает. Спасибо но как и почему оно поначалу не срабатывала ? Спасибо большое. Есть еще одна просьба У меня TextInput не работает

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/844251/Делаю-приложение-todo-на-kivy-Но-textinput-не-работает?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Это ссылка на мой вопрос Пожалуйста если знаете.

Comment: Потому что, на экран вы помещали `объект`, а в `on_start` работали с `классом объекта`, а у самого класса объекта обратились к `методу объекта`, но не вызывали его (круглых скобок нет)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое программа почти готово. Только TextInput не работает  попытаюсь скомпилировать в apk. Может сработает.